# SPSS vs R: test of flatness in profile analysis

Tags: r, spss, repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis

I'm trying to do a profile analysis on a relatively simple design, but I'm getting different numbers between R and SPSS for specifically the test of flatness

My data looks like this:

```
low, medium, high, sex
4,   1,      6,    male
3,   2,      5,    male
2,   3,      10,   male
3,   1,      13,   male
1,   5,      9,    female
3,   6,      8,    female
2,   7,      2,    female
4,   8,      1,    female
```

So I have 1 between subjects factor (sex), and 3 levels (low, medium, high) for 1 within subjects factor. N = 8

In SPSS (Analyze > GLM > Repeated Measures), I'm getting the following for my test of levels:

[image]

And this for my test of parallelism and flatness:

[image]

Then in R, I'm using the `profileR` package:

```
model <- pbg(data_long$load, data_long$sex, profile.plot=T, original.names=T)
summary(model)
```

Which gives me these results:

```
Hypothesis Tests:
$`Ho: Profiles are parallel`
  Multivariate.Test Statistic Approx.F num.df den.df     p.value
1             Wilks 0.1558453 13.54155      2      5 0.009588138
2            Pillai 0.8441547 13.54155      2      5 0.009588138
3  Hotelling-Lawley 5.4166196 13.54155      2      5 0.009588138
4               Roy 5.4166196 13.54155      2      5 0.009588138

$`Ho: Profiles have equal levels`
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
group        1  0.125  0.1250   0.128  0.733
Residuals    6  5.861  0.9769               

$`Ho: Profiles are flat`
         F df1 df2    p-value
1 10.79755   2   6 0.06084339
```

My tests of parallelism and levels are the same across both programs. But my test of flatness is different. It seems that SPSS is using (2,5) degrees of freedom, whereas R is using (2,6)

Which set of results are correct?

EDIT:

After playing with some numbers it would seem that the p value from SPSS is correct for that F value and those degrees of freedom. The p value reported from profile R does not match the F and df that it reports for the flatness test. So, is that actually an F value profileR returns? It sure says F, but the p value doesn't match the other numbers it gives me...

Comment: The development version of `profileR` available [here](https://github.com/cddesja/profileR) has fixed this problem.